# Cachemanager application for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

I'm looking for some ready-to-use cache manager application to administer cache entries. So far I found this [ASPAlliance CacheManager](http://aspalliance.com/cachemanager/default.aspx), which is fine for smaller projects but once you have hundreds of cache entries, it become hard to manage. Some basic cache entry keys filtering would be nice to have.

Thanks, Antonin

Comment: ASP.Net already has a pretty good caching mechanism.  What are your specific goals for this that aren't covered by the built-in system?

Comment: CacheManager allows you to monitor cache use, I think that's what they're looking for.

Comment: Joel, I don't want to change anything in ASP.NET caching mechanism. I just need to be able to control/administer cached items in runtime on production. Yes, I should have my app properly tested but still there can be times when you need to invalidate one or two cached items to resolve some production issue and you do not want to recycle whole app pool. 
CacheManager from ASPAlliance is a good example of what I need, it just do not provide more flexible control over cached items in terms of filtering. So I guess I'll have to write something by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the new MIcrosoft project that use to be called velocity?

not sure this is the latest link, but it is a start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645013.aspx

Also, I believe in asp.net 4.0 static Cache is no longer sealed so you can start with microsoft and move on without recoding.